# CodeDom generic type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, codedom

Is there a way to generate a class constraint with CodeDom.

Because when I use something like

```
var method = new CodeMemberMethod();
var genericParam = new CodeTypeParameter("InterfaceType");
genericParam.Constraints.Add("class");
method.TypeParameters.Add(genericParam);
```

the generated code is like

```
private InterfaceType GetImpl<InterfaceType>()
    where InterfaceType : @class
{
}
```

The best workaround i found is to use a leading whitespace before the class

```
genericParam.Constraints.Add(" class");
```

But this seems to be at best a workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is no straigntforward way to specify that constraint. Neither [for the "struct" constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(VS.80).aspx).

For the "T : new()" constraint use the flag `HasConstructorConstraint`

For the rest use CodeTypeReference as in [this msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypeparameter.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I also use zero-width space (`"\x200Bclass"`) instead of normal space. Then I replace it in final string with empty string: `.Replace("\x200B", string.Empty);`